# Restore MySQL Error

Tags: mysql

I got error in MySQL 5.7.15 below:

```
---
Enter password:
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 15: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
---
mysql> /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql> /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
-----
```

This error occurred during I restore database.

Does anyone meet this error? Could you please help to tell the solution?

Thanks,
Phanny

Answer (score 0):

several causes can lead to this, but it may be memory.

Please check your system logs to see if Kernel is killing the process due to too much memory usage.

For example:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "killed"
```

Or:

```
dmesg -T | grep -i "killed"
```

Check the memory consumption while you do the process.

For example with:

```
watch free -h
```

Can you check if your **innodb_buffer_pool_size** is too high?.

```
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024 |
+------------------------------------------+
|                           8.000000000000 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

If you are restoring to a different Server, with less memory, while keeping the settings from the main Server, that may be the problem.
In that case you may want to lower the value to make sure is not bigger than the amount of memory of your VM/Instance/Server.

Cheers